# ¿Cómo crear un archivo de texto con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear un archivo de texto en javascript que funcione para todos los navegadores.

Comment: Hola Angel y bienvenido a SO en Español. Esta pregunta no contiene código ni explica qué has intentado. Edita tu pregunta para añadir más información y poder ser más específico.

Comment: si el javascript esta ejecutando dentro del contexto del browser por temas de seguridad no puede crear archivos, imaginate si un codigo malicioso podria crear archivos? miles de paginas web con intensiones dudosas podrias generar archivo en la pc del usuario, es por eso que no puede hacerlo. Distinto seria si el contexto es una aplicacion NodeJs

Comment: URL.createObjectURL

Answer (score 13):

Puedes usar un anchor (elemento `<a>`), y especificar el `href` con una **[data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs)** que contenga el contenido a descargar y usar el atributo `download` para especificar el nombre de archivo.

Lamentablemente no puedes especificar donde se almacenara el archivo, ni si quiera si acaso se almacenara, pues depende de la decision del usuario.

```js
var contenidoDeArchivo = "Hola Mundo!";
var elem = document.getElementById('descargar');

elem.download = "archivo.txt";
elem.href = "data:application/octet-stream," 
                     + encodeURIComponent(contenidoDeArchivo);
```

```html
<a id="descargar">descarga</a>
```

Ademas, existe una API llamada [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) pero es especifica de chrome, por lo que no sirve para tu caso.

Comment: Sublime, nunca lo imagine.

Comment: Éste es un método ingenioso. Genial

Comment: Ok, vos no me dijistes esto, XD. Ya me enteré...

Comment: jaja,, por eso tienes que explicar que es lo que quieres, yo no tenia forma de saber que querías guardarlo localmente en el cliente.

Comment: Lo único que me hace falta saber es cómo crearlo en la memoria sin pulsar el botón.