# Crear y modificar un archivo en JQuery

Tags: jquery

Necesito crear archivos en el servidor, ya que son invisibles para el cliente, pero lo que he encontrado me permite crear el archivo y descargarlo al cliente, cosa que no deseo. Uno de los métodos que ví fue este:

```
var contenidoDeArchivo = "Hola Mundo!";
var elem = document.getElementById('descargar');

elem.download = "archivo.txt";
elem.href = "data:application/octet-stream," 
                 + encodeURIComponent(contenidoDeArchivo);
```

Que es una respuesta a la pregunta: [¿Cómo crear un archivo de texto con javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15509/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-archivo-de-texto-con-javascript) pero al parecer no permite personalizar las configuraciones del archivo y lo descarga al cliente.

hay alguna forma de crear archivos sin necesidad de descargarlos y solamente crearlos en la carpeta de la aplicación??

Comment: Que lenguaje de programacion estas utilizando en el servidor?

Comment: Quisiera generarlo en JQuery, ya que estoy generando otro archivo en el servidor y no quisiera que fuera repetitivo, estoy usando C#

Comment: A que te refieres cuando dices 'no me permite personalizar las configuraciones del archivo y lo descarga al cliente'?

Comment: Que quisiera definirle el nombre y sobre todo extensión del archivo, y cuando lo genera le aparece al usuario en su navegador que se está descargando el archivo, cosa que no quiero, deseo un archivo local invisible para el usuario.

Comment: Otra cosa que busco es que si el archivo ya existe se reemplace por el nuevo contenido

Comment: Has intentado algo para crear el archivo del lado del servidor? Que tecnologias utilizas? Web Forms? Mvc? Web api? Tienes que dar mas detalles.

Comment: Mmmm si, si he usado del lado del servidor, aunque para eso necesitaría saber cómo mandar un object array como parámetro a ajax. Lo que deseo hacer es guardar datos como este en un archivo:

var datos = {{nombre: Ana, apellidop: López, apellidoM: Ruíz...},{nombre: Carlos, apellidop: González, apellidoM: Martínez...},....}

Comment: Con jQuery solamente no se va a poder hacer porque se ejecuta en el lado del cliente. Para crear/modificar ficheros en el servidor vas a necesitar al menos algún script en el servidor que gestione las peticiones de JavaScript/jQuery. Lo que mandas parece un objeto simple, que podrías enviar al servidor procesándolo como JSON o como una cadena simple.

Comment: Es que he intentado mandarlo como JSON.stringify(parametros) que es el nombre del arreglo pero no sé como recibirlo del lado del servidor, uso el (string parametros) pero me dice que hay un error