# Crear archivos .txt o cualquier tipo de archivos con jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, servidor, archivo

Existe alguna manera de crear archivos con contenido a través  de `jQuery`  y alojarlo en una ruta especifica del proyecto? Estos archivos que estoy tratando de hacer pueden ser de `.txt` u otro tipo como `.php` la aplicación esta echa en `php` y se que con `php` puedo hacerlo, pero los archivos los quiero crear desde `jQuery` no se si se pueda pero si alguien tiene alguna idea es aceptada .

Comment: A ver si estos comentarios te sacan de tu duda [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108269/crear-y-modificar-un-archivo-en-jquery)

Comment: ok si, pero el archivo como se guardaría en una ruta especifica de mi servidor?

Comment: Te refieres a la función de PHP [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php)?

Comment: Javascript del lado del cliente no tiene la capacidad de realizar ningún tipo de escritura ya que este solo tiene la finalidad de interactuar y modificar el comportamiento en el DOM y se ejecuta en el navegador el cual tampoco posee esta capacidad, que no es lo mismo descargar un archivo que crearlo (ojo), como mucho podrías interactuar con las cookies o el almacenamiento local, si ya tienes un backend no veo la necesidad de querer esto, solo es cuestión de crear los endpoints para enviar los datos desde el cliente y escribirlos en el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba algo como esto:

[Crear-txt-con-javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/qm5AG/)

Pero jamas podras crearlo dentro de la carpeta de tu proyecto, esto por que javascript se ejecuta desde el lado del cliente. Para que el archivo termine en tu proyecto debes ejecutar el procedimiento desde el lado del servidor, osea desde PHP. Lo que si puedes hacer es un controlador que cree el archivo con php, y dispararlo con ajax o con una promesa.

Saludos!